# cannot read property 'object' of undefined in react during routing implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-redux

I am currently stuck on this step, or this is the first time the instructor in the video has gone to the test site.
https://thinkster.io/tutorials/react-router/creating-links

When I try to test my site, I get a blank screen.  In the console I get 4 warnings and a problem on line 49 of App.js... A line that doesn't exist until served. How do you investigate these?  When I go to that line on the test site, it directs me to a file I didn't create called Browser.js.  This is the line within a long if/else statement

```
if (typeof console !== 'undefined') {
    console.error(message);
}
```

I think the important part of the error message though is in the console where it says

```
[react-router] Location "/" did not match any routes
```

Any help would be much appreciated!  I have a feeling the issue lies within the Home folder's index.js file.  This is the link to my project on github:
https://github.com/rockomatthews/react-projects/tree/master/react-redux-realworld-example-app

Feel free to clone it and run with 'npm start'

Comment: Off topic: Add `node-modules` to your `.gitignore`

Comment: `Path` with small `p` on [line](https://github.com/rockomatthews/react-projects/blob/master/react-redux-realworld-example-app/src/index.js#L15)

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings how is this done and what should the result be? I think I kind of tried it.  Does this mean once I ignore them, that I cannot use "git add ." or else they'll just be added again?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on this line: https://github.com/rockomatthews/react-projects/blob/12d8db7fce6f96bb55b8f6396361fbe0af8442fe/react-redux-realworld-example-app/src/index.js#L15

You've capitalized `Path="/"` when it should be `path="/"`.

Comment: thanks all.  How did you find that if you don't mind me asking?  What was your thought process initially?

Comment: Well, due to the error you mentioned I checked where you defined the route and it seemed odd that it was capitalized since I've always lowercased it. Then I cloned the project, tried correcting that and it worked. Most of the times you get more useful (specific) errors, but since the router was just not able to recognize the route, it wasn't really an error (like undefined index, for example, happens at some specific line) which could be pointed to a particular line.

Comment: noted.  thank you! Would you know why I'm getting all of these warnings?  is it because of what @Boy With Silver Wings mentioned in his 'off topic' comment above?  Do I need to .gitignore node_modules? and How would one go about doing this?  I tried on my own and ignored them but then simply re-added them, I think, when I did 'git add .' the next time I commit something...